# jquery .change not triggered in ie when using .val in a .live('keyup', function()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do an input that only accept digit. I can have some dynamic input so I use the `.live` function.

On my `.live('keyup')` function I'm adding some "," which depends of the input length.
Here's a part of my code on an input (not dynamic):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#test').change(function() {
           alert('trigger change');
      });
 });


 $('#test').live('keyup', function() {
    var realDotPos = $(this).val().indexOf('.');
    var inputValue = '';
    var inputDecimals = '';
    var value = '';
    var length = 0;
    var cptMod = 0;
    var cptVirgule = 0;

    if (realDotPos == -1){
        inputValue = $(this).val().replace(/,/g, '');
    } else{
        inputValue = $(this).val().substring(0,realDotPos).replace(/,/g, '');
        inputDecimals = $(this).val().substring(realDotPos);
    }

    length = inputValue.length;
    if (length > 3){
        for(i=length-1; i>=0; --i){
            if ((cptMod != 0) && (cptMod % 3 == 0)){
                value += ',' + inputValue[i];
                ++cptVirgule;
            } else{
                value += inputValue[i];
            }
            ++cptMod;
        }
        value = value.split('').reverse().join('');
        $(this).val(value + inputDecimals);

    } else{
        $(this).val(inputValue + inputDecimals);
    }

});
```

The problem with this is that in ie, the `.change` function is not triggered when i click out of the input. FF or chrome works fine. If i remove the line `$(this).val(inputValue + inputDecimals);` the trigger works. What's wrong?

Comment: Your code is buggy at this line `var cptVirgule =`. Is there also a reason why the .live() is outside the document.ready ?

Comment: Sry i had erased some characters when pasting the code. There's no specific reason why my .live() is not in document.ready. I tried it in earlier and it didn't worked.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated. Look into using `.on()` if you're allowed to use the latest jQuery; otherwise you should still consider using `.delegate()` instead.

Comment: I tried using .on() but my problem was that I was not able to delete a dynamic input.     $('#test').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parents("tr").remove();
 });   is not working but if i put .live() that's fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/EaXLL/6/) to test your code.

The *change* event does not fire in chrome for me, neither as in IE.

What you can do is trigger the change event by calling `.change()`:

```
$(this).val(value + inputDecimals).change(); // or with .trigger('change')
```

---

**Event delegation:**

`.live()` has been deprecated in newer version of jQuery, you should look for `.on()` (in case you don't use the very latest version neither, check for [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/))

Using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with a selector will delegate the event handling and thus handle any element (represented by the selector) inserted in the dom after it is initialized.

So here I delegate to the document, the events change/keyup for all inner element which has a class '.myinput':

I've made a fiddle for you to show the updated code, and how it works when adding dynmically new inputs: http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/xw7SV/9/

Here's the updated js code (with the optimizations and event delegation):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('change', '.myinput', function(e) {
        alert('trigger change');
    });

    $('#test').on('keyup', '.myinput', function(e) {

        var $this = $(this),  // select 'this' only once
            currval =$this.val(),  // keep the initial value to work with
            newvalue = null,
            realDotPos = currval.indexOf('.'),
            inputValue = '',
            inputDecimals = '',
            value = '',
            length = 0,
            cptMod = 0,
            cptVirgule = 0;

        if (realDotPos == -1) {
            inputValue = currval.replace(/,/g, '');
        } else {
            inputValue = currval.substring(0,realDotPos).replace(/,/g, '');
            inputDecimals =currval.substring(realDotPos);
        }

        length = inputValue.length;

        if (length > 3) {

            for(i=length-1; i>=0; --i) {
                if ((cptMod != 0) && (cptMod % 3 == 0)){
                    value += ',' + inputValue[i];
                    ++cptVirgule;
                } else{
                    value += inputValue[i];
                }
                ++cptMod;
            }

            value = value.split('').reverse().join('');

            newvalue = value + inputDecimals;

        } else {
            newvalue = inputValue + inputDecimals;
        }

        $this.val(newvalue).change(); // call .change() to trigger the event

    });

});
```

---

***Some notes about your code***:

- You should save your selections: `var $this = $(this);`
- As well as the value, get it once: `var val = $this.val()`

Comment: Thx, this is working great, but what about the dynamic input. Should I do $(this).val(value + inputDecimals).on().change() or something like $(this).val(value + inputDecimals).on('change', .change()). Tried both and it's not working :s

Comment: Well I got a table with 1 row in it (input with id='test'). When I press on a button, there's a new row added (input with id='test2'). With the adding of $(this).val(value + inputDecimals).change(); this is working on the input with the id 'test' but not the 'test2'

Comment: I got it, updated the answer to show you how to cover this case ;-)